# Enforce compile time check during initialization of non-integral types

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to make sure that variables are initialized with valid data and would like to have this check carried out at compile time. The classes have a `static constexpr` method to check validity. In a simplified version it could be like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(T initValue) :
      mValue(initValue) 
    {
         assert(isValid(iniValue));
    }

    static constexpr bool isValid(T value) {
        return (value > 0);
    }        
private:
    T mValue;
};
```

Now for integral types I could use a templated function to enforce compile time checks:

```
template <typename T, T initVal>
Foo<T> make_new() {
    static_assert(Foo<T>::isValid(initVal), "is not valid");
    return  Foo<T>(initVal);
}
```

And use it like this

```
    auto saveInt = make_new<int, 3>();
```

The question is how to do that with non-integral types. I could do something like this which would trigger the assert in C++14:

```
    constexpr Foo<float> constFloat(3.0);
    Foo<float> saveFloat = constFloat;
```

Is there a maybe a more elegant way in C++>=11 which would allow me to do that with a one-liner? In the end the value I want to assign is known at compile time and so is the validity of this value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a `constexpr` check-and-return filter, with a not `consexpr` instruction (the `throw` of an exception) in it's wrong case, as follows

```
static constexpr T checkAndRet (T value)
 { return value > 0 ? value
                    : (throw std::runtime_error("invalid"), T{}); }
```

that you can apply to the value before the assignment?

```
constexpr Foo(T initValue) : mValue{checkAndRet(initValue)} 
 { }
```

So you can have a compile time error when you declare a `constexpr` value

```
constexpr Foo<float> f2 {-1.0f};  // compile time error
```

and a runtime error (an exception) otherwise

```
Foo<float> f3 {-1.0f};  // run time error
```

The following is a full working example and work starting from C++11

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    constexpr Foo(T initValue) : mValue{checkAndRet(initValue)} 
     { }

    static constexpr T checkAndRet (T value)
     { return value > 0 ? value
                        : (throw std::runtime_error("invalid"), T{}); }

private:
    T mValue;
};

int main ()
 {
   Foo<float> f0 {1.0f};               // OK
   constexpr Foo<float> f1 {1.0f};     // OK
   //constexpr Foo<float> f2 {-1.0f};  // compile time error
   Foo<float> f3 {-1.0f};              // run time error
 }
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP specify the following

> It does not solve my initial problem. Your last code line still produces an error only at runtime, i.e. initializing a `Foo<float>` variable to a value validated during compile time is not possible unless I declare the init value as `constexpr` beforehand

Sorry: I partly misunderstood your question.

Yes; it's possible, without declaring a `constexpr Foo<float>` beforehand, but the solution that come in my mind is very ugly because it's long and require the repetitions of elements.

With a C-style macro you can make it simple and elegant but I think C-style macros are distilled evil.

Anyway... if you declare the following `static constexpr` methods in `Foo`

```
static constexpr bool isValid (T value)
 { return value > 0 ? true
                    : (throw std::runtime_error("invalid"), false); }        

template <bool>
static constexpr T retV (T value)
 { return value; }
```

you can initialize a not-`constexpr` `Foo<float>` object with a `float` literal and a compile time check as follows

```
// OK
Foo<float> f0 { Foo<float>::retV<Foo<float>::isValid(1.0f)>(1.0f) };

// compilation error
// Foo<float> f1 { Foo<float>::retV<Foo<float>::isValid(-1.0f)>(-1.0f) };
```

As you can see is very ugly and you have to repeat two times the value, that is very error prone.

But if you define a C-style macro as follows

```
#define makeCValue(val) \
   Foo<decltype(val)>::retV<Foo<decltype(val)>::isValid(val)>(val)
```

You can initialize you `Foo<float>()` objects as follows

```
Foo<float> f2 { makeCValue(1.0f) };     // OK
// Foo<float> f3 { makeCValue(-1.0f) }; // compilation error
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
 {
   constexpr Foo(T initValue) : mValue{initValue} 
    { }

   static constexpr bool isValid (T value)
    { return value > 0 ? true
                       : (throw std::runtime_error("invalid"), false); }

   template <bool>
   static constexpr T retV (T value)
     { return value; }

   T mValue;
 };

#define makeCValue(val) \
   Foo<decltype(val)>::retV<Foo<decltype(val)>::isValid(val)>(val)


int main ()
 {
   // OK
   Foo<float> f0 { Foo<float>::retV<Foo<float>::isValid(1.0f)>(1.0f) };

   // compilation error
   // Foo<float> f1 { Foo<float>::retV<Foo<float>::isValid(-1.0f)>(-1.0f) };

   Foo<float> f2 { makeCValue(1.0f) };     // OK
   // Foo<float> f3 { makeCValue(-1.0f) }; // compilation error
 }
```

Obviously you can use `makeCValue()` macro only with compile time known values (literal values, `constexpr` values, ...).

Comment: Thanks. Although your API is admittingly nicer. It does not solve my initial problem. Your last code line still produces an error only at runtime, i.e. initializing a Foo<float> variable to a value validated during compile time is not possible unless I declare the init value as constexpr beforehand.

Comment: @the_summer - Sorry: I've partly misunderstood your question. Answer modifiers; hope this helps.

Comment: Very interesting appraoach with passing the result of isValid as template parameter to force compile-time evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

With the current standard no, you can't do it at compile time.

At [Albuquerque ISO C++ Committee Meeting in 2017](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7ca2sh/2017_albuquerque_iso_c_committee_reddit_trip/?st=jdvpzxmy&sh=d8330cac) there was positive feedback on Proposals for [user-defined literals for strings](https://wg21.link/P0424), [class/struct types as non-type template parameters](http://je4d.s3.amazonaws.com/D0732R0-wip.pdf), [new and delete in constexpr contexts](https://wg21.link/P0784). So in a future version of the standard (if we are luck maybe C++20) it will be possible. Until then the current restrictions only allows integral types for non-type template parameters and there is no workaround I am aware of.

As for the reason of the current limitations is mostly has to do with representation, name mangling and comparisons of values that are of a non-integer type.